# American Football constant $k$ value Air Resistance Projectile

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

***Question*** - I am trying to work out the time taken for an American football launched from head height at an angle $\theta$ to the horizontal to hit the ground. I am involving air resistance. However, I am struggling to work out how to work out / assign a value to a constant $k$. Here is my working:

I let $\mathbf{r}$ denote the position vector of the ball, so $\mathbf{\dot r}$ denotes the velocity. $\mathbf{u}$ denotes the crosswind force / velocity of air. So air resistance must be $-k(\mathbf{\dot r} - \mathbf{u})$ as it will be proportional to the difference in velocity between the ball and air.

I then use $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$ to give $m\mathbf{\ddot r} = m\mathbf{g}-k(\mathbf{\dot r} - \mathbf{u})$.

This gives the differential equation $\mathbf{\ddot r} + \frac{k}{m}\mathbf{\dot r} = \mathbf{g} + \frac{k}{m}\mathbf{u}$.

I solved this to give $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{C_1} + \mathbf{C_2}e^{\frac{-kt}{m}}+(\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{u})t$.

The initial conditions must be $\mathbf{r}(0) = \mathbf{H}$ as the ball is launched from a displacement $\mathbf{H}$ above the ground. Also, $\mathbf{\dot r}(0) = \mathbf{V}$ as the ball is launched with an initial velocity $\mathbf{V}$.

This gives $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{C_1} + \mathbf{C_2}$ and $\mathbf{V}=-\frac{k}{m}\mathbf{C_2}e^{\frac{-kt}{m}} + \frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g} + \mathbf{u}$.

Solving I got $\mathbf{C_1}=\mathbf{H}+\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{V}-\frac{m^2}{k^2}\mathbf{g}-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{C_2} =-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{V}+\frac{m^2}{k^2}\mathbf{g}+\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{u}$.

So the particular solution is $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{H}+\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{V}-\frac{m^2}{k^2}\mathbf{g}-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{u} + (-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{V}+\frac{m^2}{k^2}\mathbf{g}+\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{u})e^{\frac{-kt}{m}} + (\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g} + \mathbf{u})t$.

After factorising I have: $\mathbf{r} = $ $\mathbf{H} + \frac{m}{k}(\mathbf{V}-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{u}+(-\mathbf{V}+\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{u})e^{\frac{-kt}{m}})+(\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g} + \mathbf{u})t$

So, $\mathbf{r}=$ $\mathbf{H}+ \frac{m}{k}(\mathbf{V}-\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{u})(1-e^{\frac{-kt}{m}})+(\frac{m}{k}\mathbf{g} + \mathbf{u})t$.

Now notice that the vectors can be written as:
$\mathbf{V} = V \cos{\theta}\mathbf{i}+ V \sin{\theta}\mathbf{k} $, $\mathbf{g} = -g{\mathbf{k}}$, $\mathbf{u} = u\mathbf{j}$.

This gives: $\mathbf{r} = H\mathbf{k} + \frac{m}{k}\left(V\cos{\theta}\mathbf{i} + V\sin{\theta}\mathbf{k}+\frac{mg}{k}\mathbf{k}-u\mathbf{j}\right)\left(1-e^{\frac{-k}{m}t}\right)+\left(-\frac{mg}{k}\mathbf{k}+u\mathbf{j}\right)t$.

***Now I will solve for $t$ and work out when ball hits ground***

The ball hits the ground when the $\mathbf{k}$ coefficient is $0$. So I have $H + \frac{m}{k}(1-e^{\frac{-k}{m}t})V \sin{\theta} + \frac{m}{k}(1-e^{\frac{-k}{m}t})\frac{mg}{k} + -\frac{mg}{k} = 0$.

***My issue / problem***

I have $H=1.79, g=9.81, m = 0.43, V = 14.3$. I choose $\theta = 55^\circ$ but I guess this could be any reasonable value. How do I find out $k$ though ?

I understand that there isn't a set value for this as it depends on the ball. Can anyone give me a reasonable value for $k$ for an American football ? I used a value of $0.07$ because I let $mg=kv$ where $v$ is the terminal velocity of the ball to solve for $k$. However, this gave me a value for time $t$ of $2.8$ seconds. I guess **I need to know the terminal velocity of an American football / rugby ball - does anyone know this value ?**

I know $2.8$ seconds is way too small, so my question is if there is anything I have done wrong in my working in setting the model up and solving ? I would really appreciate this help

Comment: 2.8 sec is quite a long time for a thrown ball, why do you think it is way too small?

Comment: @Paul My model is the rugby ball being thrown over a house and we have to see whether it is possible for a student to run through the house to the other side and catch the ball. I don't see how a rugby ball thrown at $14$ metres per second at an angle of above $50$ degrees doesn't remain in the air for longer

Comment: @Paul Also, I then found for the time of $2.8$ seconds the horizontal distance travelled by subbing in for the $\mathbf{i}$ coefficient, and it was about $15$ metres. How can a rugby ball be in the air for $2.8$ seconds, reach its max height, and then fall back to the ground in $2.8$ seconds travelling $15$ metres in total horizontally?

Comment: If you throw a ball at $14$ meters per second straight upward, it takes $14/9.8\approx 1.43$ seconds to come to rest at the top of its trajectory, and another $1.43$ seconds to return. At $55$ degrees your initial vertical velocity is less so the time is less. I think you need to recalibrate your intuitions about projectiles.

Comment: The air resistance of a projectile is proportional to the **square** of its velocity.

Comment: @DavidK I know that it should be the square, but in my notes we kept it without the square. I think it's because otherwise we wouldn't be able to solve the differential equation

Comment: @DavidK why I was sceptical was because when I did it without air resistance (but launched from ground level instead) at an angle of about $65$ degrees, the ball took about $13$ seconds to hit the ground (launched at the same initial speed). would air resistance make that much of a difference to the horizontal displacement ?

Comment: $13$ seconds seems incorrect. Without air resistance, that would be $6.5$ seconds to go up and $6.5$ seconds to come down. Falling for $6.5$ seconds from the top of the trajectory, the football would be traveling $9.8\cdot6.5$ m/s in the vertical component alone, which is a lot more than $14$ m/s. As for how to infer a reasonable number to use in a linear model of air resistance, I'd suggest using something that doesn't overestimate the drag at your fastest velocity. That would rule out using the terminal velocity to estimate the constant.

Comment: @DavidK apologies, the time calculated without air resistance was $2.7$ seconds. I think with air resistance when I calculated I got about $2.5$ so that would be feasible ?

Comment: @DavidK What would you suggest using for $k$ then ?

Comment: @DavidK I got $t = 2.3$ seconds. To work out how far the ball travels horizontally, I should substitue this into the $\mathbf{i}$ component right ? I end up with $22.5$ metres which is surely way too large

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathbf{k}$ coefficient is
$$\frac{m \left(1-e^{-\frac{k t}{m}}\right) \left(\frac{g m}{k}+V \sin (\theta )\right)}{k}-\frac{g m t}{k}+H=0$$

The solution for the flight time $t_{flight}$ is:

$$t_{flight}\to \frac{m W\left(-\frac{(g m+k V \sin (\theta )) e^{-\frac{k (H k+m V \sin (\theta ))}{g m^2}-1}}{g m}\right)}{k}+\frac{H k}{g m}+\frac{V \sin (\theta )}{g}+\frac{m}{k}$$

with $W(z)$ the Lambert W-Function (ProductLog).

Substituting your numeric values we get $t_{flight} \simeq 2.41338$, but not $2.8$

The $\mathbf{i}$ coefficient is

$$\text{x}(t)\to \frac{m V \cos (\theta ) \left(1-e^{-\frac{k t}{m}}\right)}{k}$$

Hence the horizontal distance travelled is

$$x(t_{flight}) \simeq 16.3693$$

Comment: I will accept your answer. That's what I got which is good. To calculate horizontal distance travelled, do you substitute the $t$ value into the $\mathbf{i}$ coefficient ? I got around $20$metres from memory which seems too high